# flagStrap set value from an AJAX responce

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When loading values for the edit/update form values, I use the following code to set the country value in `flagStrap` country dropdown. All attributes are set with the value but it is not selected on the dropdown.

```
$('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','CN');
$('#select_country').flagStrap();

<div class="flagstrap col-md-6" id="select_country" data-input-name="NewBuyer_country" data-selected-country=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your 2 lines of jQuery code are not executed 
because I just tried your code and it works fine, please see
[Country dropdown with flags using FlagStrap](http://ibootstrap.net/Snippets/IDXdoA7)

You could try to put a breakpoint to verify that your code is executed. If it's not, you could update your question with the whole javascript code ...

Comment: <label>Select Country</label><br>
        <button type="button" id="btn2">Click me</button>
        <div class="flagstrap" id="select_country" data-input-name="NewBuyer_country" data-selected-country=""></div>
    
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','CN');
    $('#select_country').flagStrap();
    
    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        $('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','LK');
        $('#select_country').flagStrap();
    });
});
</script>    This kind of a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select Country</label><br>
        <button type="button" id="btn2">Click me</button>
<div class="flagstrap" id="select_country" data-input-name="NewBuyer_country" data-selected-country=""></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','CN');
    $('#select_country').flagStrap();

    $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
        $('#select_country').attr('data-selected-country','LK');
        $('#select_country').flagStrap();
    });
});
</script>
```

It works on form load but not on button click. That's my problem.